# Fraction and Decimal: Reciprocal of x's non-integer

Tags: fractions

The reciprocal part of $x$'s non-integer decimal part equals $x+1$, and $x>0$. What is $x$?

Solution: I tried this way-

Let's $n$= integer part of $x$

$1/x-n = x+1$

or, $1=(x-n)(x+1)$

or, $1= x^2+x-nx-n$

or, $x^2+ (1-n)x -(n+1)=0$

but, stucked here. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete [Ashvin Swaminathan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/259604)'s answer:

$$x = \frac{n-1 \pm \sqrt{n^2 + 2n + 5}}{2}$$

Because $x > 0$, we take
$$x = \frac{n-1 + \sqrt{n^2 + 2n + 5}}{2}$$

Since the discriminant $n^2 + 2n + 5 = (n+1)^2 + 4 \geq 4$, then there are indeed infinitely many solutions, and these depend on $n = \lfloor{x}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $x$ using the quadratic formula. As stated, there are infinitely many solutions...